# Is there any way to unsubscribe from all the parse channel in one call in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, channel, unsubscribe

I am developing an android app In that everything is working fine. I just want to ask that is there any way to unsubscribe from all the parse channel in one call instead of using :

```
ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground("channel1");
```

checked on google and parse android api didn't find any way to do that.

Comment: I'd say you have your answer.  I don't think the Parse API has methods that aren't in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Channels information are written in the Installation class. Simply clear the "channels" column.

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.remove("channels");
installation.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {  // or saveInBackground
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        // TODO: add code here
    }
});
```